# Is 'that' correct in the sentence "Where do you live that it's morning for you?"

Tags: grammaticality

I wonder how to best phrase this. The idea was to ask someone about their time zone.

> "Where do you live **that** it's morning for you?"

The 'that' feels off / like a literal translation from Czech.

> "Where do you live **where** it's morning for you?"

The double 'where' feels weird too.

Are these sentences correct / do they feel natural for native speakers?

Comment: The use of 'that' as a conjunction (= 'in that' / 'seeing that', or 'which gives rise to the fact that') has just been covered. It's at least heading for archaic, and sounds very unnatural here. "Where do you live? ... I ask as it's morning for you there." is more natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is gramatically sound. Although, IMO it doesn't feel that natural. I would replace that by so to make it "Where do you live so it's morning for you?", but I guess it would depend on context.